# Find items in jquery chosen in selenium

Tags: c#, jquery, selenium, jquery-chosen

I am very new to Selenium. On our webpage developers have used jQuery chosen select to fill dropdown. What I want to do is pass specific text and select matching text I entered.

So I tried this:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id=MyDrpdown_chosen]//div[@class='chosen-drop']//div[contains(@class,'chosen-search')]/input"), CacheLookup]
    private HtmlElement _selectItem;

_selectItem.SendKeys("Banana");
```

**Update 1**

Here is screenshot of source inspection in debugger tool

[image]

But I get error that it couldn't find matching element. Can someone guide me?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @DebanjanB update the question

Answer (score 0):

//div[@id=MyDropdown_chosen]

has to be

//div[@id='MyDropdown_chosen']

(you are missing the single quote)

Comment: i added singe quotes but it says element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1: Just change your dropdown id

like this : MyDrpdown_chosen

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id=MyDrpdown_chosen]//div[@class='chosen-drop']//div[contains(@class,'chosen-search')]/input"), CacheLookup]
    private HtmlElement _selectItem;

_selectItem.SendKeys("Banana");
```

Comment: how does fit the way i am accessing the elements?

Comment: also if you see there is no tagname with option.. all elements are inside li tag

Comment: Could you explain more what do you need exactly?

Comment: i think i explained very detailed on what i want. What you would like to know more?

Comment: You have specific text from where ? And you matching with what exactly?

Comment: i just want to be able to search string from dropdown i want. Hope this clears your doubts

Comment: I understand now mate. You should change your dropdownid

Comment: Sorry for misguiding. I did typo but that was for example purpose I posted that code and changed actual id.. that codr doesn’t work

Comment: Why you using Contains in your xpath. It always be "chosen-search". Maybe contain not working.

"//div[@id=MyDrpdown_chosen]//div[@class='chosen-drop']//div[@class='chosen-search']/input"

Answer (score 0):

If your code is faster than the results are updating you can have a problem finding or interacting with your element. You should make sure you wait enough time for the list to update.

Also note the typo and the missing quotes around MyDrpdown_chosen.